# Button still visible even if path sets to false

Tags: c#, xaml

```
 <Button
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        ToolTip="Convert selected Node(s)"
        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="False"
        Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource serviceLocator}, Path=NetworkManager.NetworkViewModel.IsGenericProfileLoaded}"
        Command="{Binding Path=ConvertToNonControlPlaneCommand}" >
        <Image
            Style="{StaticResource toolbarImageStyle}"
            Source="/Resources/Icons/equipment_edit.png"
            />

    </Button>
```

The button should be collapsed or invisible depending on the Path property called IsGenericProfileLoaded. Even if IsGenericProfileLoaded is false, the button is still visible. How to make it invisible. From other question on stackoverflow, it seems that i need to visibilitytoBoolean converter or is there anything that I can use here like disable="true"?

Comment: [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when a data binding does not work, debug the app in Visual Studio and look in the debug output. You can show the debug output by: menu / DEBUG / Windows / Output. Go in the application to that page and keep an eye to the messages shown in the debug output window. You will get some information about what does not work.

You are correct, in your case you need a converter. The data binding alone will not be able to assign a bool to a dependency property of type Visibility.

Here is a very simple version of such convertor:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool booleanValue = (value as bool?).GetValueOrDefault();
        return booleanValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You will have to also add somewhere in XAML a static reference that makes this convertor available. Maybe in App.xaml something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:<replace_with_your_namespace>;assembly=<replace_with_your_assembly>">
    ...

    <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />

    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your case the visibility will have to be set like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource serviceLocator}, Path=NetworkManager.NetworkViewModel.IsGenericProfileLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

You will soon see that you need more flexibility from the convertor. You will want to convert a true to Visibility.Collapsed and a false to Visibility.Visible. Here is how such a more flexible convertor would be used in XAML:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsLocked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=not}"
```

And here is how the convertor method would have to be rewritten:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool booleanValue = (value as bool?).GetValueOrDefault();
    if (parameter != null)
    {
        if (parameter.ToString().Equals("not", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            booleanValue = !booleanValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Invalid value for the BoolToVisibilityConverter parameter: '{0}'. The only valid values are null or 'not' (case insensitive)", parameter));
        }
    }

    return booleanValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```